# how to add and condition in filter in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make `filter` in jquery .I am able to make `individual` filter .But both filter not work at same time

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/suhukuyavu/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){
  var arr=[];
      //all li
    console.log($('ul li'))
$('#matchselector').on("change",function() {
   //Your code here
  console.log(this.value );
  var val = $(this).val();
    $('ul li').hide();
    $('ul').find('.team-' + val).show();

});

  $('#venueselector').on("change",function() {
   //Your code here
  console.log(this.value );
  var val = $(this).val();
    $('ul li').hide();
    $('ul').find('.venue-' + val).show();

});
})
```

- when I select `Mumbai Indians` from first dropdown .It show correct  result .It show three result (matches with **Mumbai Indians**)
- Run JS again select `Mumbai`**venue** from venue drop down it show correct result (two result which have venue "`Mumbai`")

**Expected out put**
 - if I select `Sunrisers Hyderabad` from team and `venue` to be `Mumbai` it should show only one result **(Mumbai Indians vs Sunrisers Hyderabad)**

Comment: Seems to work mostly fine. The only apparent bug I could find was selecting "All" produces an empty list.

Comment: it is not giving correct result

Comment: it is not giving common result ..In other words using both `select` value it is not giving common solution..check expected output

Comment: see if I select `Sunrisers Hyderabad` from team and `venue` to be `Mumbai` it should show only one result **(Mumbai Indians vs Sunrisers Hyderabad)** ..currently it is giving two result

Comment: @user944513 check my Answer, hope it helps =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare all filters at same time. Here's a generic approach that isn't dependent on quantity of filters. For example you could quickly add another filter select by only adding the class prefix it uses and it's id selector

Solution creates an array of the filter classes and joins them to create selector to show

```js
$(function() {

  var $items = $('li[itemprop="subEvent"]');
  // used to create class selectors based on select id
  var classPrefixes = {
    matchselector :'.team-',
    venueselector:'.venue-'
  }

  var $sels = $('#matchselector, #venueselector').on("change", filterItems);

  function filterItems() {
    // filter selects with relevant values
    var filterClasses = $sels.filter(function(i, select) {   
        return select.value !== 'All'
      // map those values to array of class selectors
      }).map(function(i,select) {      
        return classPrefixes[select.id] +select.value
      }).get();

    if (filterClasses.length) {
       // hide all then show matching classes
       $items.hide().filter(filterClasses.join('')).show();      
    } else {
      // show all when no filter classes
      $items.show();
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Team:::
<select id="matchselector">
  <option value="All">All</option>

  <option value="MI">Mumbai Indians</option>
  <option value="SRH">Sunrisers Hyderabad</option>
  <option value="RCB">Royal Challengers Bangalore</option>
  <option value="GL">Gujarat Lions</option>
  <option value="RPS">Rising Pune Supergiant</option>
  <option value="KXIP">Kings XI Punjab</option>

</select>
venue::
<select id="venueselector">
  <option value="All">All</option>

  <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
  <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
  <option value="Rajkot">Rajkot</option>
  <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>

</select>

<ul>
  <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-MI team-SRH venue-Mumbai live">
    <div class="matchdetails">
      <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Mumbai Indians vs Sunrisers Hyderabad</div>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-KKR team-KXIP venue-Kolkata">
    <div class="matchdetails">
      <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Kolkata Knight Riders vs Kings XI Punjab</div>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-RCB team-MI venue-Bengaluru">
    <div class="matchdetails">
      <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Royal Challengers Bangalore vs Mumbai Indians</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-GL team-RPS venue-Rajkot">
    <div class="matchdetails">
      <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Gujarat Lions vs Rising Pune Supergiant</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-KKR team-SRH venue-Kolkata">
    <div class="matchdetails">
      <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Kolkata Knight Riders vs Sunrisers Hyderabad</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-DD team-KXIP venue-Delhi">
    <div class="matchdetails">
      <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Delhi Daredevils vs Kings XI Punjab</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-MI team-GL venue-Mumbai">
    <div class="matchdetails">
      <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Mumbai Indians vs Gujarat Lions</div>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is.
1st you hide everything then display the one match `team`, but when you pick the 2nd one youo hide everything again then display the one match `venue`, you will never get the correct result.

to fix this, I moved both change event to one and call another function `update()`

in update we get val() selected from both select list then compare,
you can have 4 situation:

1. both ALL, just display all
2. team = All and venue = xxx, then display everything match venue
3. venue = All and team = xxx, then display everything match team
4. team = xxx and venue = yyy, then match both using:

   `$('ul').find('.team-' + team + '.venue-' + venue).show();`

DONE!

```js
$('#matchselector, #venueselector').on("change", update);

function update() {
  var venue = $('#venueselector').val();
  var team = $('#matchselector').val();

  $('ul li').hide();
  if (venue === 'All' && team === 'All') {
    $('ul li').show();
  } else if (team === 'All') {
    $('ul').find('.venue-' + venue).show();
  } else if (venue === 'All') {
    $('ul').find('.team-' + team).show();
  } else {
    $('ul').find('.team-' + team + '.venue-' + venue).show();
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  Team:::
  <select id="matchselector">
     <option value="All">All</option>

   <option value="MI">Mumbai Indians</option>
  <option value="SRH">Sunrisers Hyderabad</option>
  <option value="RCB">Royal Challengers Bangalore</option>
  <option value="GL">Gujarat Lions</option>
  <option value="RPS">Rising Pune Supergiant</option>
  <option value="KXIP">Kings XI Punjab</option>

  </select> venue::
  <select id="venueselector">
     <option value="All">All</option>

   <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
  <option value="Kolkata">Kolkata</option>
  <option value="Bangalore">Bangalore</option>
  <option value="Rajkot">Rajkot</option>
  <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>

  </select>

  <ul>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-MI team-SRH venue-Mumbai live">
      <div class="matchdetails">
        <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Mumbai Indians vs Sunrisers Hyderabad</div>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-KKR team-KXIP venue-Kolkata">
      <div class="matchdetails">
        <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Kolkata Knight Riders vs Kings XI Punjab</div>

      </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-RCB team-MI venue-Bengaluru">
      <div class="matchdetails">
        <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Royal Challengers Bangalore vs Mumbai Indians</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-GL team-RPS venue-Rajkot">
      <div class="matchdetails">
        <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Gujarat Lions vs Rising Pune Supergiant</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-KKR team-SRH venue-Kolkata">
      <div class="matchdetails">
        <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Kolkata Knight Riders vs Sunrisers Hyderabad</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-DD team-KXIP venue-Delhi">
      <div class="matchdetails">
        <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Delhi Daredevils vs Kings XI Punjab</div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li itemscope="" itemprop="subEvent" class="team-MI team-GL venue-Mumbai">
      <div class="matchdetails">
        <div itemprop="performer" class="match-teams">Mumbai Indians vs Gujarat Lions</div>
      </div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: FYI `$('#venueselector').val()` returns same as `$('#venueselector').find(":selected").val()`